# How should I get rid of an SSL error on accessing parked domain in https using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, dns

I'm a beginner in .htaccess and I need help. We have this website with its store module in https. We also have a parked domain pointing to this website. The problem is, when I type "https://www.parked_domain_name.com/store/" in the address bar, I get an SSL error. However, when I type "http://www.parked_domain_name.com/store/" on the address bar, it redirects to "https://www.parked_domain_name.com/store/" without getting any SSL errors. How can I view the store w/o SSL errors when I type "https://www.parked_domain_name.com/store/" in the address bar?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Seems this question should be asked on http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can only have HTTPS running on a single domain name for a site.

There are exceptions, for example a certificate for *.example.org would let you run HTTPS on both www.example.org and web.example.org subdomains.  Also, some certificate providers will issue certificates for a fixed list of several domain names.

But in common usage, one IP address can have only one certificate, and one certificate can have only one domain name.

The behaviour you describe of the http URL redirecting the the https URL without warnings does not sound like it is possible.  Perhaps try a few different browsers - they all act a bit differently on this front.  How you reached the URL is not relevant.  If you access example.org over HTTP and the certificate says anotherdomain.com then you will get SSL warnings.

You're best off running the site **only** on e.g. https://example.org/ and **redirecting** any other domains to that one, rather than hosting the site from multiple domains.

I hope this helps.